# Facing a problem while implementing stack navigation in React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, hybrid-mobile-app, react-native-navigation

So I am just starting with working on react native Expo and facing some trouble in implementing stack navigation in my expo react native application.
App works fine without navigation, but as soon as I try to implement stack navigator I get an error saying ***Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.........***

I've attached the error, code and package.json screenshots below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJbaN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2BAJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3yOt.png)

```js
{
  "name": "signature-silver-service-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.1",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-image-picker": "^13.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "galio-framework": "^0.8.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```js
// import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Topbar from './Components/Topbar';
import MainScreen from './Components/MainScreen';
import styles from './Css/styles';
import AddNewItem from './Components/NewItemForm';
import SearchScreen from './Components/SearchScreen';

// const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {



  return (
    // <View style={styles.container}>
    //   <StatusBar
    //     hidden={true}
    //   />
    //   <Topbar title="Solrose" style={styles.topBar} ></Topbar>

      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={MainScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Main Screen' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="AddNewItem" component={AddNewItem} options={{ title: 'Add New Item' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} options={{ title: 'Search Orders' }} />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    // </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: What Version of React-Navigation are you useing?

Comment: @ColinHale "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: I'll write an answer and please tell me if it's work for you.

Comment: Looks like you haven't created the Stack navigator with the CreateStackNavigator function to initialize it

Comment: @ColinHale its still the same error, I actually tried using CreateStackNavigator earlier.

Comment: Can you make an example for the problem on https://snack.expo.dev/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `createStackNavigator` and import it from `@react-navigation-stack` to make it work like this:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation-stack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Topbar from './Components/Topbar';
import MainScreen from './Components/MainScreen';
import styles from './Css/styles';
import AddNewItem from './Components/NewItemForm';
import SearchScreen from './Components/SearchScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={MainScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Main Screen' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="AddNewItem" component={AddNewItem} options={{ title: 'Add New Item' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} options={{ title: 'Search Orders' }} />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

You can check the working demo from [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@louay12/signature-silver).

Comment: actually I already used it before, if you see my code you will find it commented, anyways I've used your code but still its the same error.

Comment: Can you make an example for the problem on https://snack.expo.dev/

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@usama334/signature-silver

Comment: I've updated my answer and add a link to the working example :D

Comment: Thanks @Louay, you saved my day. Can you specify the error, what I was doing wrong?

Comment: You're welcome please set it as a correct answer, and the error in the import of `stack navigation` you need to import it from `@react-navigation-stack` to make it work :D

Comment: `import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation-stack';`